# Which is more stable: isobutylene or cis-2‐butene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, isomers

How do you compare which is more stable without using the heat of hydrogenation or combustion or any other numeric factual value: 
$\ce{(CH3)2-C=CH2}$ or $\ce{CH3-CH=CH-CH3}$ (cis)?

Comment: Wouldn't we expect the most substituted alkene to be most (thermodynamically) stable?

Comment: @electronpusher both the compounds have two methyl groups each.

Comment: @Karl I was taught "fill in the correct term for two substituents at the same carbon">trans>cis

Comment: Numbers are better than intuition. Both alkenes have the same molecular formula. Heats of Formation (kcal/mol) are helpful: isobutylene (-4.3), (Z)-2-butene (-1.7).

Comment: @Groverkss You're right http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/de/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/alkene/alkene_kiel.vlu/Page/vsc/de/ch/2/oc/stoffklassen/systematik_struktur/acyclische_verbindungen/ungesaettigte_kohlenwasserstoffe/monoene_monoine/alkene/stabilitaet.vscml.html

Comment: @user5519, I need logic; the reason behind this.